# Can I simplify this XSLT to the less-verbose form?

Tags: xml, xslt

I mostly have statements like this in my XSLT:

```
<RealisationRelation name='' 
                     xmi.id="{concat($serverxmiid, ':', $infraservicexmiid)}" 
                     xmi.type='I' 
                     from="{$serverxmiid}" 
                     to="{$infraservicexmiid}" />
```

Which is not that verbose and easier to read. But how do I create such a simple statement instead of a verbose one for this?

```
<xsl:element name="AccessRelation">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="xmi.id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat( $infraservicexmiid, ':', $artifactxmiid)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="xmi.type">
        <xsl:text>I</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="from">
        <xsl:value-of select="$infraservicexmiid"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="to">
        <xsl:value-of select="$artifactxmiid"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <MM_Profile>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:text>AccessRelation</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </MM_Profile>
    <MM_Value>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:text>accessType</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:text>w</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </MM_Value>
</xsl:element>
```

I'm wondering how I get these `MM_Profile` and `MM_Value` parts in that less verbose form. The others are easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your XSLT simplified to use **[literal result elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#literal-result-element)** and **[attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates)**:

```
<AccessRelation name=""
                xmi.id="{$infraservicexmiid}:{$artifactxmiid}"
                xmi.type="I"
                from="{$infraservicexmiid}"
                to="{$artifactxmiid}">
  <MM_Profile name="AccessRelation"/>
  <MM_Value name="accessType" value="w"/>
</AccessRelation>
```

It's the same as you've already done for `RealisationRelation` (and Martin Honnen helpfully reaffirms and names, +1), plus the notion that literal result elements can be embedded within other literal result elements.

[**Creating element nodes using `xsl:element`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-element) is rare but can be helpful when the element name has to be computed as opposed to being known in advance.

Comment: You can also replace `xmi.id="{concat( $infraservicexmiid, ':', $artifactxmiid)}"` by `xmi.id="{$infraservicexmiid}:{$artifactxmiid}"`

Comment: Yes, that's even better.  Answer updated.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Can I do that last trick also with

`<xsl:variable name="clustername" select="concat('[', $cluster,'] ', $clustertype, ' (Node)')"/>`? At some point I tried to do this but the parser choked on it so I did something wrong.

Comment: No, attribute value templates aren't for `select` attributes but for literal results elements such as shown in this answer.  Your alternative to `xsl:variable/@select` would be to use a combination of `xsl:text` and `xsl:value-of` as children to `xsl:variable`, but that'd be more, not less, verbose.

Comment: In XSLT 3.0 (with expand-text enabled) you can do `<xsl:variable name="cn" as="xs:string">[{$cluster}] {$clustertype} (Node)</xsl:variable>`

Answer (score 3):

Use literal result elements, as you already do, simply define the attributes as well, e.g. `<MM_Profile name="AccessRelation"/>` and `<MM_Value name="accessType" value="w"/>`. If you need to compute (part of) an attribute value then do that with attribute value templates, as in e.g. `<AccessRelation xmi.id="{$infraservicexmiid}:{$artifactxmiid}" from="{$infraservicexmiid}"></AccessRelation>`.